# Unable to append html page name in Url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

These are my two html files indexAf.html and HomeAF.html.

indexAf.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hlfabric">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AF Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleAf.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="appHLVL.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrlAf">
        <div ng-include="template.url"></div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

HomeAF.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hlfabric">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AF Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleAf.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="appHLVL.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

js file

```
var appHlVl = angular.module('hlfabric', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

appHlVl.controller('AppCtrlAf', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.templates = [ {
        url : 'LoginAf.html'
    }, {
        url : 'HomeAF.html'
    } ];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
    $scope.login = function(username, password) {
        if (username === 'AFBlockchain' && password === 'Value12') {
            //authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
            $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
            $scope.user = username;
        }else{
            $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination";
        }

        ;
    };

});
```

While navigating from indexAf.html to HomeAF.html the page is navigating but the url is not changing(not appending HomeAF.html) instead of indexAf.html. I want to change the url while navigating from one page to another page.

Comment: Where are you changing the url ? Post your config file

Comment: I'm changing in js file using ng-include

Comment: You are only changing the template using ng-include not the url. If you want to implement routing in angularjs, please check https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router